# xquery --- get to the next node with a different value than the current one

Tags: xml, xpath, xquery

Here is the xml I am working with and I am trying to the the id number of the first different pd value I encountered.

```
<result>
  <pd>a</pd>
  <id>1</id>
  <pd>a</pd>
  <id>2</id>

  <pd>b</pd>
  <id>8</id>

  <pd>c</pd>
  <id>9</id>
  <pd>c</pd>
  <id>4</id>

  <pd>d</pd>
  <id>7</id>
</result>
```

so the result that I am expecting is:

```
 <pd>a</pd>
 <id>1</id>

 <pd>b</pd>
 <id>8</id>

 <pd>c</pd>
 <id>9</id>

 <pd>d</pd>
 <id>7</id>
```

I used following-sibling::*[2] to get to the next pd and compare that with the current node but then it only gave me b, not c and d. Can any of you give me a hint on how to iterate through the whole xml to get the desired output? Thanks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There may be more elegant solutions, but the strategy I took was to gather all of the distinct values in the pd elements, then loop through *all* of the pd elements and grab the first sibling where the value in the pd element matched the value in the current iteration of the distinct values.

```
for $distinct-pd in fn:distinct-values($xml//pd)
  for $pd in $xml//pd[./text() eq $distinct-pd][1]
    return ($pd, $pd/following-sibling::*[1])
```

For your code, this yields

```
<pd>a</pd>
<id>1</id>
<pd>b</pd>
<id>8</id>
<pd>c</pd>
<id>9</id>
<pd>d</pd>
<id>7</id>
```

Answer (score 1):

**Another way of achieving the same -- good enough for not very long sequences:**

```
/*/pd[not(. = preceding-sibling::pd)]
               /(.|following-sibling::id[1])
```

**When this XPath 2.0 expression (and XQuery) is evaluated against the provided XML document:**

```
<result>
  <pd>a</pd>
  <id>1</id>
  <pd>a</pd>
  <id>2</id>

  <pd>b</pd>
  <id>8</id>

  <pd>c</pd>
  <id>9</id>
  <pd>c</pd>
  <id>4</id>

  <pd>d</pd>
  <id>7</id>
</result>
```

**the wanted, correct result is produced**:

```
<pd>a</pd>
<id>1</id>
<pd>b</pd>
<id>8</id>
<pd>c</pd>
<id>9</id>
<pd>d</pd>
<id>7</id>
```