# increment the position value of an index every time in for loop in xquery

Tags: xquery, marklogic

```
 xquery version "1.0-ml";
 import module namespace admin = "http://marklogic.com/xdmp/admin" 
  at "/MarkLogic/admin.xqy";
 declare variable $totalhosts := xdmp:host-name(xdmp:group- 
 hosts(xdmp:group()));

 for $h in $totalhosts
 let $ind := fn:index-of($h, 2)
  return $h[$ind]
```

If somehwere i put in the code
let $ind :=2
and then i return $ind it should return the value at index ind=2

I am putting my question in another way- the above code does not return me the host name , i have 5 hosts in my cluster/group.

also within the same loop i want to increment the value of $h each time it iterates.

Please help how can I do this

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13538108/xquery-get-to-the-next-node-with-a-different-value-than-the-current-one have you seen the answers?

Comment: It would be helpful if you provided a complete example, including values for `$t` and `$phases`, and the expected output. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example for some more instructions.

Answer (score 2):

It is not entirely clear what you are looking for. I assume you just want the index of the items from the sequence of `$totalhosts`.

For that, you can use the `at` operator in your `for` loop:

```
for $h at $i in $totalhosts
return ($h, $i)
```

Comment: ok, if i put somewhere let $i=2 and then i return $h[$i] it should return me the value of index=2 but it doesnt how do i do that?

Comment: `$h` will be the single item within the loop. If you want to select the Nth host from the full set, then you want to be pulling from `$totalhosts`, not `$h`: `$totalhosts[$i]`